# Does Google Hangouts live streaming have a viewer count limit?

Tags: hangouts-on-air

Looking at the [Hangouts On Air common questions](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2459411?hl=en&ref_topic=2553242) - and within those FAQs under "Invites and Viewership" there is this question, **How many people will be able to watch the broadcast?** with this answer:

> Your broadcast will be viewable by the public once you click Start broadcast from within the Hangout On Air. The number of viewers watching your broadcast is displayed at the top of the video call window next to the “Embed” link.

Thing is the answer is either vague, or doesn't answer the question; meaning does the "viewable by the public" mean 1000s of people, or those within some unstated maximum.

Just to be clear, I'm not referring to how many people are able to outbound stream from within the hangout, which I believe is limited to ten users - but how many users are able to view a live stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no stated upper limit because there really isn't a maximum of Hangout viewers.

> There is no limit for the number of viewers who can watch the live broadcast. However, if you do believe that you will have an extremely large event with a lot of users, please do reach out and let us know.
>
> -- [Dori, Google Community Manager](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plus-discuss/k_Cxp-V4ntk), 28 May 2013

Comment: +1 Thank you so much; curious, what Google search did use to find that page, or did you just know to try limiting the search to the "productforums.google.com" sub-domain?

Comment: "hangouts maximum viewers" turns up the link in the third here. Not sure if it does on your locale